# Why doesn't touchesBegan in sprite kit allow me to access the sprite name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

When I check my touch event with a breakpoint I notice the touched node that I detect with the following code doesn't have a .name.  Any help?  Any other way I can possibly check which node I've touched.  I want my nodes to represent parts of the body and believe creating physics bodies for each body part might slow the app down.

The following is my code.  Not very complex:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKSpriteNode *touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene];


    //if touched node equal to one of these then ...
    if([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"head.png"]){
        [self alert:@"User has touched the head: " Message:@"Thank You."];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SKNode's name property is not set by call SKSpriteNode initWithImageNamed: Name's are purely for game logic. From SKNode reference guide.

> This property is used to identify a node in other parts of your game
>   logic. For example, you might use this name as part of collision
>   testing. You can also search for nodes in a tree by their name.

If you haven't explicitly set the name property of an SKNode it will not be set.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks so much.